# Spring Boot and OAuth2, WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter vs ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

What is the difference between `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` and which should have higher precedence?

I don't really see difference if I am both resource owner and the client. I can configure`HttpSecurity` in both classes.

EDIT:

Which type of matchers should I add in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and which in `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`? I found in some examples that `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` matches pages for login, registration etc. and `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` for the real resource. Is that a correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter for adjust the access rules and paths that are protected by OAuth2 security (Some additional oauth2 filters activated).

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter for the basic Spring Security customization.